# Check multiple conditions is empty php

Tags: php

I want to check the user has selected any one of the input field,
I 've tried like ,

```
 if(empty($_POST["month"]) and  ($_POST["eid"]))
 {
 ...
 }
```

But the condition is true when I'm using || opertator and the condition is false when I'm using &&.Why it is not working for && operator.How can I solve this?

Comment: try `if(!empty($_POST["month"]) || !empty($_POST["eid"]))`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a statement like:

```
if ($condition1 || $condition2) {}
```

returns `TRUE` when `$condition1` OR `$condition2` is true.

And, a statement like:

```
if ($condition1 && $condition2) {}
```

returns `TRUE` when both `$condition1` AND `$condition2` are true.

In your case, you need to use:

```
if(! empty($_POST["month"]) || ! empty($_POST["eid"])) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I want to check the user has selected any one of the input field*

Based on above statement, you can simply check for using `isset()`:

```
if(isset($_POST["month"]) || isset($_POST["eid"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of checking:

Has the user filled at least one of the fields is basically asking Are all the fields empty? If not - the user has checked at least one field, otherwise - none.

So simply use the && operator and add ! to the whole condition.

```
if(! ( empty($_POST['field1']) && empty($_POST['field2']) ... ) ) {
}
```

**Edit:**
OP's condition:

> I've three set of filelds like date1 and date2 ,id and date, month If
>   user selects nothing from these three sets I want to display a message
>   if the user select any one of the sets they can go in.

I hope I have understood you right. If not, please share an example.

- set 1 - date1 and date2
- set 2 - id and date
- set 3 - month

Code:

```
if( (empty($_POST['date1']) and empty($_POST['date2'])) or
    (empty($_POST['id']) and empty($_POST['date'])) or 
    (empty($_POST['month'])) ){
  echo 'your message here.';
} else {
  //the user can go in.
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to check like `   if((empty($_POST["date"]) and ($_POST["eid"])) or (empty($_POST["date1"]) and ($_POST["date2"])))
`

Comment: Please share your exact requirement so I could write a condition that suits to your case. (in plain words, "eid" and "date" are required fields?)

Comment: I ve three set of filelds like date1 and date2 ,id and date, month If user selects nothing from these three sets I want to display a message if the user select any one of the sets they can go in.

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: In case it helped, please consider up voting and accepting my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for checking empty field, while you use `&&` the code is not working because `($_POST["eid"])` have no rules.

Example :

```
//You check the month are empty and the eid are ... ?
if(empty($_POST["month"]) && ($_POST["eid"]))

//Use this if you want to check the "month" and "eid" are Empty
if(empty($_POST["month"]) && empty($_POST["eid"])) {
   ... your validation here ...
}

//You can you is_null too
if(is_null($_POST["month"]) && is_null($_POST["eid"])) {
   ... your validation here ...
}
```

If you want to validate only one between `$_POST["month"]` or `$_POST["eid"]` just change the `&&` to `||`.

Answer (score 0):

A compact way to do it is to make an array of all the values then check if they are empty.

```
If(empty(array($_POST["month"], $_POST["eid"]))){
// They are both empty
}else{
// Not empty
}
```